# Can you travel on state highways through Navajo Nation land during the time of Covid restrictions?

Tags: covid-19, arizona

Currently there is a [curfew](https://www.navajo-nsn.gov) in the Navajo Nation due to the Covid-19 pandemic. In particular, from Saturday nights until Monday mornings in September [there is a lockdown](https://www.navajo-nsn.gov/News%20Releases/NNDOH/2020/Sep/NDOH%20Public%20Health%20Emergency%20Order%202020-022%20Dikos%20Ntsaaigii-19.pdf), and (I believe all the time right now) the [Navajo Nation's roads are closed to visitors](https://www.navajo-nsn.gov/News%20Releases/NNDOH/2020/Aug/NDOH%20Public%20Health%20Emergency%20Order%202020-021%20Dikos%20Ntsaaigii-19.pdf). Does this mean that you can't drive through the Navajo Nation on state highways traversing the reservation, such as 160? Does whether or not it is during the curfew make a difference? I'm not sure whether or not state highways count as Nation roads.

I'm not planning on stopping or leaving the state highway, I would just be traveling through.

Comment: Route 160 is a U.S. highway, not state, in case it makes a difference (probably doesn't).

Comment: If major through routes like US-160 were closed, I'd expect to see prominent alerts on official road status websites such as https://az511.gov/.  But I don't.  So my guess is that the closure only applies to local roads.

Comment: @NateEldredge Nice reasoning!

Comment: @NateEldredge despite the name, US highways are built and maintained by the states.

Comment: @phoog: I know, and that's why it probably doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @NateEldredge I would have thought so too, but I found a news story with pictures of roadblocks on what looked like highways, so I figured I had better be sure since it would be a long detour if it wasn't open.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Local news from August](https://www.570news.com/2020/08/17/stay-at-home-order-lifted-as-navajo-nation-starts-reopening/) indicates that county, state and federal highways aren't included in the road closure order.

> The resolution closes Navajo-owned and maintained roads, about 5,000 miles, to outside tourists and visitors. County, state, federal roads aren’t included, but Shorty said that shouldn’t be construed as an invitation for tourism.

So you should be fine if you stay on such roads and don't drive into Navajo roads.

Answer (score 6):

I crossed the Navajo Nation back in June.

At that time, the curfew was only in effect at night. I did not try to cross during it.

There was no problem driving on 98, 160 or 163. The only road block I came across was on the road leading into Monument Valley Tribal Park.

I stopped at a gas station and was impressed at the care everyone was taking to distance, mask and clean hands. I made sure to take extreme caution as well and was made to feel welcome despite a very out of state license plate.